# Intellisense shows 'typeof import "/path"' - how to get intellisense of imported variables?

Tags: typescript, intellisense, es6-modules

When I import some data and hover over the variable, it shows `'typeof import "/some/path"'` instead of a list of the variables.

I would like it to show the list to enable autocomplete and such things.

I made an [example project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-issue-typeof-import?file=index.ts,stuff%2Ftheme.ts,stuff%2Findex.ts,stuff%2Fvariables%2Findex.ts,stuff%2Fvariables%2Fvars1.ts,stuff%2Fvariables%2Fvars2.ts).

If you hover over `theme1` in `index.ts` of that project, it shows vars: `typeof import("some/path");`

The way it happens is:

A folder has files with named exports. There is an index.ts file which exports everything from that folder:

```
//stuff/variables/index.ts
export * from '.';
```

.

```
//stuff/variables/vars1.ts
const stuff1 = 'stuff1';
const stuff2 = 'stuff2';
const stuff3 = 'stuff3';

export { stuff1, stuff2, stuff3 };
```

A file in the parent folder imports all from that index.ts file, and exports it as a variable:

```
//stuff/index.ts
import * as variablesData from './variables/index';

export const vars = variablesData;
```

Another file imports that variable and includes it in an exported object:

```
//stuff/theme.ts
import { vars } from './index';
    
const obj = {
  blue: 'blue',
};

export const theme1 = {
 ...obj,
 vars,
};
```

And lastly, the top index.ts imports that named export.

```
//index.ts
import { theme1 } from './stuff/theme';
console.log(theme1);
```

If I hover over that imported variable, it doesn't list the variables, but instead it shows  `typeof import("some/path");`

So the `export * from '.'` is not resolved by intellisense. Can't I use `"export *" ?

Can this be helped by adding some type or writing it in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

*I believe that what you are describing is a bug/missing feature in Typescript itself. Though I did not find it among github issues upon doing an ultra quick search there.*

What you can do is define the `vars` variable directly in `vars1.ts` file.

```
//stuff/variables/vars1.ts
const stuff1 = 'stuff1';
const stuff2 = 'stuff2';
const stuff3 = 'stuff3';

const vars = { stuff1, stuff2, stuff3 };

export { stuff1, stuff2, stuff3, vars };
```

Then adjust your index file

```
//stuff/index.ts
export { vars } from './variables/index';
```

and your intellisense will work beautifully.

Yes this approach is a little bit more work than you did, but at least the types work now :).